# Converting input numerical strings to integers in C

Tags: c, string, integer

I am trying to convert numerical strings inputs to integer. When I type 2 my output is 0

```
    scanf( "%d", betNumber );
    printf("What number do you want to bet? \n");
    printf("Here is your number: %d\n" ,atoi(betNumber));
```

User input = 2 or 3 or 5
Output = always 0

Comment: Is `betNumber` a pointer?

Comment: I suggest you not use `scanf`. Use [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/). Easier to get your head around and less error prone.

Comment: Anyway, you should really compile with warnings enabled, this kind of error is pretty easy to spot for the compiler; try to compile with gcc (with `-Wall`) or with clang.

Comment: betNumber is  char betNumber[];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never use the `*scanf` family, nor `atoi` and friends.  The correct way to write this code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
  char inbuf[80], *endp;
  unsigned long bet;  /* negative bets don't make sense */

  puts("What number do you want to bet?");
  if (!fgets(inbuf, sizeof inbuf, stdin))
    return 1;  /* EOF - just quit */

  errno = 0;
  bet = strtoul(inbuf, &endp, 10);
  if (endp == inbuf || *endp != '\n' || errno) {
    fputs("invalid number entered, or junk after number\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }

  printf("Here is your number: %lu\n", bet);
  return 0;
}
```

Some exposition, perhaps:

The only sane way to read input from the user in C is *an entire line at a time*.  If you don't, you are very likely to get in trouble when, not if, the user types more input than you expected.  The ideal way to do this is with [`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline), but many C libraries do not have it, and it does make you remember to free the line-buffer.  Failing that, [`fgets`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) is good enough for many purposes, as shown here.

The only *correct* way to convert text to machine numbers in C is with the [`strto*`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) family of functions.  I use the word *correct* very deliberately.  All the alternatives either silently ignore numeric overflow (`ato*`) or, worse, *trigger undefined behavior* on numeric overflow (`*scanf`).  The usage pattern for `strto*` is a little tricky, but once you get used to it, it is just boilerplate to be memorized and typed.  I'll take it apart for you:

```
errno = 0;
```

It is necessary to clear `errno` manually before calling `strto*`, because a syntactically valid number that overflows the range of the return value is reported *only* by setting `errno`, but success does *not* clear `errno`.  (The manpage says that a particular numeric value is returned, but that value could have resulted from correct input, so that's no help.)

```
bet = strtoul(inbuf, &endp, 10);
```

When this function call returns, `bet` will be the number you wanted, and `endp` will be set to the first character in `inbuf` that is not a digit.

```
if (endp == inbuf || *endp != '\n' || errno) { /* error */ }
```

If `endp` equals `inbuf`, that means *there were no digits*, which is usually not considered a valid number.

If `*endp` is not equal to `'\n'`, that means *either* there was something else on the line after the number, *or* `fgets` did not read the whole line; in either case, again, the input is not as expected.  (All 64-bit unsigned numbers fit in fewer than 80 characters.)

And if `errno` is nonzero, numeric overflow occurred.

Comment: Suggest testing `errno` against `ERANGE`.  I agree `strto*()` is better, but it too has holes.  The multi-thread safely of `errno` is not specified in C.  Many `strtoul()` surprisingly (and IMHO wrongly) accept negative numbers.  sizeof(int) may be < sizeof(long) and additional range tests then needed for converting to `int`.  `strto*()` (and `*scanf()`) is specified in locale "C" only as "In other than the "C" locale, additional locale-specific subject sequence forms may be accepted". Locale switching to from "C" has thread safe concerns.

Comment: @chux If `strto*` happened to return some other E-code, would that indicate success? It would not. How should you respond to such a failure? The exact same way you do for `ERANGE`. Therefore, it is correct to check only for nonzero `errno`.  Moreover, `errno` *is* required to be thread-safe in both POSIX and C11 (C11 being the first revision of the C standard that has any concept of threads) (see e.g. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_398 : "Each thread has its own ... errno value.")  Your other points are valid, though.

Comment: @Zack Thanks for the ref, although I was unable to find in spec C11 concerning the thread attributes of `errno`.  Might you know where?

Comment: @chux N1570, section 7.5 (specifying `<errno.h>`): ... `errno` [is a macro which] expands to a modifiable lvalue that has type `int` *and thread local storage duration*.  (Emphasis mine.)  See 6.2.4p4 for the definition of thread-local storage duration (referred to there as "thread storage duration" for some reason, but in context I'm >99% sure that's an editing mistake rather than a meaningful distinction).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you not use `scanf`, nor any of it's disreputable coterie of insidious companions. Use [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/). Easier to get your head around and less error prone. atoi is a less-safe equivalent of strtol.

But... atoi takes a pointer to char. So if this compiles...

```
printf("Here is your number: %d\n" ,atoi(betNumber));
```

...then betNumber must be:

```
char betNumber[100];
```

...or something like that. Which explains what's wrong with the call to scanf.

scanf("%d", p) expects that you'll be passing it a pointer to int, not a pointer to char. It reads text from standard input, converts it to an integer, and assigns it to the int variable -- or what it *assumes must be* an int variable -- that the pointer is pointing to. There is no type checking there, there can't be. The compiler can't tell that you passed the wrong thing (a C compiler could be written to validate scanf's arguments against the format string, but the general tendency with C compilers has always been to politely let you shoot yourself in the foot (modulo gcc -Wall, thanks @Zack), and rightly so).

Comment: `gcc -Wall` does in fact parse `scanf` (and `printf`) format strings and warn about argument mismatches, but (as you can tell from my answer) I am entirely in agreement with the advice not to use `scanf` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `scanf()` properly, such as

```
int betNumber;
scanf("%d", &betNumber);
```

then after `scanf()` returns successfully, the value of `betNumber` already is an integer, you do not need to convert it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

scanf and atoi both take a pointer to some previously allocated storage. Here's a working example:

```
int betNumber;
printf("What number do you want to bet?\n");
scanf("%d", &betNumber);
printf("Here is your number: %d\n", betNumber);
```